# How to set no-store in om.vaadin.server.StreamResource

Tags: web-applications, httpresponse, java-11, vaadin7, websecurity

I have a vaadin 7 application to download a csv file. when I set the `streamResource.setCacheTime(0);` Cache-Control: no-cache set in reponse header of the csv file.
but how to set no-store also in the response header of the resource. I just want to stop retaining my csv file in browser. so the attacker can not  use it.
following method not works `streamResource.getStream().setParameter("Cache-Control",  "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");`

nor this one also

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control",  "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`streamResource.getStream().setParameter(...)` does not work because `getStream()` creates a new instance every time it's invoked.

What you could do is to create a custom subclass of `StreamResource` that overrides `getStream()` to make further changes to the original stream before returning it, i.e. something like this:

```java
public class NoStoreStreamResource extends StreamResource {
  public NoStoreStreamResource(StreamSource streamSource, String filename) {
    super(streamSource, filename);
  }
  
  @Override
  public DownloadStream getStream() {
    DownloadStream ds = super.getStream();
    ds.setParameter("Cache-Control",  "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
    return ds;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct but cannot applied to my situation. Is there any alternative way? something like applying a filter?

Comment: Depending on circumstances, it might be possible to override the appropriate `handleConnectorRequest` method (there are three of them used in different cases) to apply the headers. The next step from that would be to add a Vaadin `RequestHandler` that identifies specific requests and injects a header value into the response, or replace the appropriate existing one with a custom version. Then there's also the possibility of a Servlet `Filter` that does something similar, or a processing rule in a frontend server (e.g. `RewriteRule` with Apache httpd).